# How to populate owner field from a formula field?

Tags: apex, owner

I have 2 object : one and two. 
Onject two had a field named prop__c and I want to put the value of this field in the Owner field of the object one, is it possible ?

The prop__c field is a formula field and the formula is : `Conc__c.Owner.Id`

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Edited Answer:**

Owner field is a lookup to User object.
You can only put a User Id or Queue Id (for Leads and Cases) in that field.
if Prop__c contains a User Id than you can do that.

Comment: Ok, my field Prop__c is a formula field that contains this formula : `Conc__c.Owner.Id` is that possible too ?

Comment: Yes, you can do it. You can achieve this using trigger (might be process also) depending on the object schema.

Comment: When I put someting like : `acc.Owner = a.Prop__c;` with acc an account and a an sObject, it says 'Illegal assignment from string to user', maybe it is not possible even with the formula ?

Comment: Are you doing that in trigger?

Comment: In an hadler that I call in a trigger, how do you think I should put that statement ?

Comment: Convert the string to Id
String a = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
Id i = Id.valueOf(a);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39894/discussion-between-c0depirate-and-dou).

Comment: `OwnerId` can contain the Id of a `Group` as well often times...

Answer (score 0):

Unless Prop__c is a lookup to user then this would not be possible.

If it is then a trigger can be used to copy this over or a workflow

This [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2013/10/behind-the-scenes-of-record-ownership-in-salesforce.html) explains why Salesforce record ownership is set up the way it is.

Comment: Prop__c is a formula field which stores UserId. This is possible using trigger or process.